# Laravel 5.4 checking if chunk is first chunk

Tags: php, laravel-5, chunking

I'm trying to set a condition check whether the chunk is the first batch of chunk or not.

Anyone know how to check what the chunk id or something similar for example:

```
@foreach($item->chunk(3) as $item_chunk
    @if(chunk is first chunk)
        <div class="carousel-item active">
    @else
        <div class="carousel-item">
    @endif

    @foreach($item_chunk as $item)
        {{-- Do something --}}
    @endforeach 
@endforeach
```

Appreciate it if someone knows of a way to check whether the chunked list is first or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check loop using [`$loop` variable](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/blade#the-loop-variable).

```
@foreach($item->chunk(3) as $item_chunk)
    @if($loop->first)
        <div class="carousel-item active">
    @else
        <div class="carousel-item">
    @endif

    @foreach($item_chunk as $item)
        {{-- Do something --}}
    @endforeach 
@endforeach
```

Comment: Please consider linking to the documentation where this can be found.

Answer (score 0):

For sliders

```
            <div class="carousel-inner">
              @foreach($item_hr as $count => $valuetopproducts)
                <div class="item {!! $count == 0 ? 'active' : '' !!}">
                      <a href="{{ url('asset_details')}}/{{$valuetopproducts->assetid}}"><img src="{{Storage::url('wp/thumbnail')}}/{{$valuetopproducts->imagename}}" class="img-responsive" alt="{!! \Illuminate\Support\Str::words($valuetopproducts->assetname, 10,'...')  !!}"></a>
                </div>
              @endforeach
            </div>
```